# grep between two strings if pattern in the middle linux

Tags: regex, linux, awk, sed, grep

i want to grep between two strings only if there is a pattern between them.
for example, in this text:
first wanted string is Start, second is END, and the pattern is 1 2 3 each in a new line.

```
Start
abc
abc
1
2
3
abc
END
bla
bla
Start
abc
abc
1
2
4
abc
END
bla
bla
Start
abc
abc
1
2
3
abc
abc
END
```

the result should be:

```
Start
abc
abc
1
2
3
abc
END

Start
abc
abc
1
2
3
abc
abc
END
```

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -ne '/Start/{:a;N;/END/!b a;/\n1\n2\n3\n/p}'
```

Line by line:

we need only text starting with 'Start':

```
sed -ne '/Start/{
```

we found 'Start', now add everything up to 'END' to pattern space;

set label named 'a':

```
         :a
```

add next line to pattern space:

```
         N
```

if not found 'END' - jump to 'a'

```
         /END/!b a
```

now check if we have desired pattern that contain 1 2 3 and print

they will be separated by '\n' as they were on separate lines

```
         /\n1\n2\n3\n/p
         }'
```

Comment: This error is caused by your bash interpreting ! from sed command as special character, you should use single quotes as I did in example command.

Answer (score 0):

grep is not suitable, use sed instead

`sed -n "/Start/,/END/p" input.txt`

should work. I'm assuming input in a file input.txt.

Comment: just missing the *pattern inside*